# Where(and how) are the sys/socket.h network socket functions implemeneted?

Tags: sockets, network-programming

So I downloaded and compiled the FreeBSD Sys/Socket.h header and I noticed that it contains the socket function prototypes but no implementation. Windows sockets uses a DLL which implements these functions but Windows stuff is closed source. If I wanted to do network program using Linux where can the implementation headers be found? Can one write them oneself? To use a network I/O device requires operating system calls. So my idea would be to make a system call to the kernel to open the device and supply the memory address where the frames are to be written to. WITHOUT having to write an a whole new device driver mind you.

Comment: I would simply checkout the [source repository](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/) and search it (using grep, or an IDE) for the implementations of the functions in question.

Comment: Why would you want the actual implementation? You can do network programming without it, I would actually recommend against trying to read any networking stack implementation as it's often some of the most complicated subsystems in an operating system. And the plural "subsystems" is not a spelling mistake, as the networking stack is often several subsystems spread out over the operating system and its kernel.

Comment: Joachim, Im extremely interested in understanding how network functions work on the most basic level as well as writing device drivers for network adapters.

Comment: If you really want to know the implementation I recommend you to try and find a copy of W. Richard Stevens book [TCP/IP Illustrated volume 2: The Implementation](http://www.amazon.com/TCP-IP-Illustrated-Vol-Implementation/dp/020163354X/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1358106908&sr=8-3&keywords=tcp%2Fip+illustrated+volume+2).

Answer (score 0):

On Unix socket functions are in [C library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libc). These are mostly thin wrappers around OS [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call). If you are on Linux, look for source of [GLibC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library).

Comment: Nikolai, does the GCC include GLibC with socket functions?

Comment: I believe GCC and GLIBC are separate projects.